# Can an alternate physics system be devised in which the weak force is reduced or eliminated entirely?

Tags: physics, alternate-reality, quantum, weak-force

Like, is there a modification to the Standard Model you could make, or some sort of alternate gauge theory that only unifies the strong and the electromagnetic interactions?

Edit: I am not asking for the physical consequences of turning off the weak force. That is beyond the scope of this question, although I am certainly exploring that. I am just asking if there can be a way to explain why, and only, the weak force is absent or significantly reduced in this universe I'm exploring.

I think you might have to go with a different gauge group than SU(2), such that you reproduce the $W_3$ boson but not the other $W_1$ and $W_2$ bosons. Then you can use the same Weinberg mixing angle and leave electromagnetism and Higgs vacuum expectation value unchanged. At least, if I understood the explanations of electroweak theory correctly. A simple solution is probably to add a field that suppresses if I'm using the term correctly, the weak force. However, I feel like that is inelegant.

Comment: It is not clear to me if you are asking 1) for a new theory that describes physics as it is today without using the notion of weak force, or  2) if you are asking the physical consequences of "turning off" the weak interaction, leaving all else identical, 3) you are asking if we can make up some new speculative physics so we can get rid of the weak force without having everything falling apart. I think only option 2) would be suitable for this SE

Comment: Kind of something like option 2 - i'll include an edit for clarification

Answer (score 1):

In proton-proton nucleosynthesis, conversion of deuteron into deuterium is mediated by weak force. I guess you will [have to explain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakless_universe) how to make your sun shine first. Otherwise, see the Wikipedia piece.

Otherwise, electroweak force may probably break down at different boundary and therefore, probably, make weak interactions improbable (cross section of effectively zero?).

Comment: What do you mean by breaking down at a different boundary? Doesn't reducing the coupling of SU(2) also cause problems with electromagnetism and the Higgs vacuum expectation value?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, but I find it plausible that it's possible that electromagnetism would work as it does, but weak interactions become highly improbable, and that probably will have to do with energies at which the symmetry breaking takes place.